# Background grid warping when zooming in User Persp

Tags: interface, 3d-view

- New Install
- Blender 2.7b
- Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Whenever I zoom in User Perspective mode, the background grid warps alot as you can see on the bottom right of the first image below:

[image: blender zoomed in]

it returns to normal when I zoom out or in orthographic mode:

[image: blender zoomed out]
[image: blender ortho]

I think this might be because of the small screen size that I have (1366x768), or because of some settings in Ubuntu, but I can't quite work it out. What should I do to fix this problem because it is very annoying. Thank you for your time.

--A Blender newbie

Answer (score 4):

This is a normal wide-angle perspective distortion. To reduce it, you need to look at your subject through a longer lens from further away.

Bring up your right-hand panel (hotkey N) find the 'view' section, and change the 'lens' length to a higher number, and track back using the middle mouse wheel.

The longer the lens, and the further away you pull back the camera, the more closely the view will approximate to orthogonal, just as in real-life photography.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. However it doesn't fix my problem. Is there a way to completely remove the distortion? I tried higher 'lens' parameters but I still prefer the default one. I've also watched some tutorials on YouTube that has the same lens settings I have but doesn't have any distortion. Maybe it's a problem specific to my computer/version of Blender?

Comment: There's more to it than perspective; I'm pretty sure the lines to the right of the cube in the first image shouldn't be doing what they are doing. Looks like a bug, and an exceptionally weird one at that. @Mike What GPU do you have? Does it still do this using the latest version of blender? (2.78)

Comment: Thank you @gandalf3. Yes this is indeed a very weird bug in Blender 2.76. I just upgraded to 2.78 and it worked flawlessly. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Mike Glad it worked out :) Since it indeed turned out to be a bug, I've closed your question. Nothing to worry about, doesn't mean you did anything wrong. (I thought I'd mention this as this appears to be your first question. So, welcome!)